# Sharing google chrome extension information across users

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

My problem is simple : I would like to do some statistics on a website my friends and I visit.

So I would like to find a way to connect each instance of my info-gathering google chrome extension in order to gather them in a common place for analysis.

As a first thougt, one ideal solution would be to get read-write access to a shared google drive spreadsheet, but I am open to other solutions.

Is it feasible ? Can anyone point me to the good direction ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/20450438/3278057

Answer (score 0):

A spreadsheet is easy and works well for few users and rows, however the easiest way is to use google analytics, extensions support them and there are samples for custom events.
If you go the spreadsheet route use appendrow to avoid concurrency issues.
You would need to use oauth for spreadsheet access or set sharing to public write.
For a more sophisticated solution with total control of the data and scalability use Google bigquery.